# XM Cloud - The server failed to fulfill a request (GET) from Azure Function

Tags: azure, xm-cloud, api

```
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics; // Include this for logging

namespace XmCloudSXAStarter
{
public class OpenAlertCommand : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        CallAzureFunctionAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private async Task CallAzureFunctionAsync()
    {
        string azureFunctionUrl = "https://xmcloud-test-function.azurewebsites.net/api/SitecoreProxyService?code=QkXhAyPcJSodxwFQSPLdkDQ0NBPPZ5a4DPCYe3TSdtCNAzFuu_AgXw==";
        Log.Debug($"OpenAlertCommand: Making call to Azure", this);
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(azureFunctionUrl);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throws an exception if the HTTP response status is not a success status code.
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Response from Azure Function:");
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur during the HTTP request
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Error from Azure Function:");
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I have a C# function linked to a custom ribbon in a Sitecore CMS. This function is designed to send requests to an Azure function, which is publicly accessible and doesn't require authentication. Accessing the Azure function's URL directly from a browser works fine, and I receive the expected response.

However, when I attempt to trigger this function by clicking the ribbon button in the Sitecore CMS, the browser hangs and eventually, I receive a "The server failed to fulfill a request" error from Sitecore, indicating that the origin web server timed out while responding.

I'm struggling to identify the missing element in this setup. Interestingly, when I set up a separate service (not within Sitecore) to interact with the Azure function, it operates correctly.

I'm looking for guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.

P/s: The Pop-up alert work fine unless I trigger HTTP request

Comment: FYI, the seperate service was setup on localhost

Comment: Are you testing this locally in Docker or deployed to XM Cloud.  As a side note - this is not the right way to do this on XM Cloud, integrations with other systems should be done via web hooks and api's. This is exactly the type of thing that Sitecore Connect is there for.